# variance-covariance matrix of a "zeroinfl" object

Tags: regression-coefficients, count-data, zero-inflation

There is a command in R to derive the variance-covariance matrix of a glm (model) objects. Does any one know if there is a command which one can derive variance-covariance matrix of a Zero inflated Poisson regression model object?

Comment: what do you mean by VC matrix of a model? please add some details

Comment: I mean covariance matrix of all coefficients in the model. Anyways, I got my answer, I can simply used the command "vcov".

Answer (score 1):

"vcov" is the command. It gives covariance matrix of all coefficients in the model (derived from the Hessian of the optim output).